# How to Copy Row then Insert Into Another Sheet on specific row then delete original

Tags: excel, vba

I have spent more time then I want to admit on this.  I have found this code online and it works well if I want to copy the contents of a row based a specific cell value to the end of another sheet within the same workbook.  However, I would like to insert the row to a specific row on the other sheet and move the contents down.  Is there a way to do this?

```
Sub MoveRow_DeleteOriginal()
Dim rg As Range
Dim xc As Range
Dim p As Long
Dim q As Long
Dim r As Long
p = Worksheets("Open Projects").UsedRange.Rows.Count
q = Worksheets("Closed Projects").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If q = 1 Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Closed Projects").UsedRange) = 0 Then q = 0
End If
Set rg = Worksheets("Open Projects").Range("M5:M" & p)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For r = 1 To rg.Count
If CStr(rg(r).Value) = "Complete" Then
rg(r).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Closed Proejcts").Range("A" & q + 1)
rg(r).EntireRow.Delete
If CStr(rg(r).Value) = "Complete" Then
r = r - 1
End If
q = q + 1
x = x + 1
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D%5Bvba%5D+insert+row Also, do yourself (and everyone else who has to read it) a favor and learn to properly indent your code. Doing so makes it much more readable, and it's much easier to trace the flow of execution. Code that isn't properly indented is pretty much unreadable without a lot of extra effort, which usually isn't worth it, because code written that way is usually very wrong.

Comment: example if you want to insert on row 17: `rg(r).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("Closed Proejcts").Rows("17:17").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    rg(r).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: There is a way. You need to explain in more detail what the code is currently doing and what you want it to do. Adding screenshots of your data before and after will help a great deal. Also, providing sample data as text will certainly help. I almost forgot, `On Error Resume Next` gotta go.